# Calculate number of working days between two dates

Tags: 2013, calendar, calculated-column

In SP2013 calendar list I have calculated column that calculates number of working days between two dates. It gives accurate number of working days until user puts weekend day as End date, than it calculates one more day (Saturday as working day).
Code for calculated column is bellow:

```
=(DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"D"))-INT(DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([End Time])-WEEKDAY([Start Time]))<0,2,0)+1
```

Any advice what to change in formula or if you know where can I find working one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this formula

```
IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”)),””,(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”))+1-INT(DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],”d”)/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([EndDate])-WEEKDAY([StartDate]))<0,2,0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate])=7,WEEKDAY([StartDate])=7),AND(WEEKDAY([EndDate])=1,WEEKDAY([StartDate])=1)),1,0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([StartDate])=1,(WEEKDAY([EndDate])-WEEKDAY([StartDate]))>0),1,0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([StartDate])=7),WEEKDAY([EndDate])=7),1,0))
```

Comment: It still gives me incorrect answer.

Comment: It is working fine, I tested it. Do you not want it to count the day it starts? e.g. Tues to Friday is 4 days, and Tues to next Tues is 6 days.

Comment: If I put from Tuesday to Saturday it counts as 5 working days, but it should count 4. So it is not working for me.

Comment: I updated the formula above to take care of that case. Nice catch :)

Comment: hey Ransher, what about if the user only needs to select ONE DATE, does the above code count the 1 day only for that specified date??

Comment: actually, just tested it and added 1 between the "" and it works :) haah fantasticooooooooooooooooo

Comment: i tried using the formula, but i am getting count 2 where the duration is 1 day.

Comment: also, if i removed, +1, i am getting correct value for a single day event but a day less when its a multiple days event