# Calculated field exclude weekends

Tags: sharepoint-server, date

I am working on custom  list which has startDate field and endDate field. I am using to calculated field to find the duration between those fields. I am trying to exclude the weekends.

Comment: Check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/197828/58747