# Sharepoint List counting days in queue since ticket created

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there formula for calculated column to track days since ticket was created in SharePoint list? Only counts business days/. This is my formula =TODAY()-Created but its counting all days. Also is there way stop the counting once status of ticket is complete?

Comment: What is your formula?? Edit your question and post it.

Comment: @teylyn formula is =TODAY()-Created i apologize. Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried to search? There are so many results from a google search. one of them here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197827/calculate-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @teylyn yes i have tried to search this sir

Comment: @teylyn those are for start to end calculation what i want doesn't have a end its just tracks the days since opened.

Comment: use Today() instead of a stored end date.

Answer (score 1):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create a Calculated Column named "Today"
**Formula:**

```
=TODAY()
```

[image]

2.Create another Calculated Column named "WorkDays"

**Formula:**

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF([Created],[Today],"d")),"",(DATEDIF([Created],[Today],"d"))+1-INT(DATEDIF([Created],[Today],"d")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([Today])-WEEKDAY([Created]))<0,2,0)-IF(OR(AND(WEEKDAY([Today])=7,WEEKDAY([Created])=7),AND(WEEKDAY([Today])=1,WEEKDAY([Created])=1)),1,0)-IF(AND(WEEKDAY([Created])=1,(WEEKDAY([Today])-WEEKDAY([Created]))>0),1.0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY([Created])=7),WEEKDAY([Today])=7),1,0))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: works great Thank you!

Comment: Hi kidus. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.